# Why doesn't Blender use my GPU?

Tags: rendering, image, gpu

I have a i7 with 32 GB RAM & an Nvidia 1070, Windows 10.
My GPU shows up in Blender, but when I try to render a still jpeg, it crashes 100% of the time.
In my Task Manager, my RAM maxes out before the crash and my GPU stays at 0% usage.
After about 10 crashes, I updated my Nvidia driver and I've had 4 more crashes. I even tried just checking the 1070 alone under CUDA - same result: 0% usage.
What is going on here?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe changing tile parameters- this blender guru tutorial can have good tips. [Eighteen ways to speed up cycles rendering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gSyEpt4-60&list=PLBSVQqzB6k6Wl10BNgdrLO7XmCP6jLdP5&index=1)

Comment: Do you have a very large scene? If so, then it may not fit into your graphics card's 8gb of VRAM.